# How to play local mp3 files with MediaElement

Tags: c#, silverlight

I'm creating a simple media player with Silverlight 4 (C#). Now I'm using the MediaElement but it gives me an error

> error 4001: .... System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal

Now this error happens when I want to set the source of the MediaElement. So when the user hits "Play", it sets the source of the first song.

```
Song s = afspeelijst.ElementAt(currentPlayingIndex);
media.Source = new System.Uri(s.FilePath);
media.Position = TimeSpan.Zero;
media.Play();
```

The next code doesn't work either, but it removes the error. But still no sound :s

```
media.SetSource(new FileStream(s.FilePath, FileMode.Open));
```

Comment: Where does s.FilePath point to? SL does not allow applications to access local file system (except for isolated storage). Is file part of the application package?

Comment: No the path is for example c:\music\song.mp3 and this is converted to file:///c:\music\song.mp3. The application needs to be installed, so it can access local file system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to check out this code. It worked just fine for me :)

```
mediaElement1.LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Manual;
mediaElement1.Source = new Uri(@"D:/ExamplePath/myVideoFile.avi");
//@ means that the string behind is a path so / won't be 
//treated like a special character
mediaElement1.Play();
```

Answer (score 2):

In Silverlight 4 you can access local files in specific user folders (My Documents, My Music, My Pictures and My  Videos) or sub folders within these. (Out of browser with elevated privileges enabled).

Modifying your code above would change it to something similar below.

```
string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "test/song.mp3");


            media.SetSource(new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open));
            media.Position = TimeSpan.Zero;
            media.Play();
```

I hope this helps

Comment: I tried that, didn't work. I found out, when you call SetSource() it downloads the file. So in the download delegate when it reached 100%, I hit Play() and that works. I just tested my solution with HTTP, not local.

Comment: What operating system are you on? Windows 7 handles it differently than it shows .. Libraries/Documents might be confused with C:\Users\Account_name\Documents ... i tried on my machine and it worked. you might be able to get it to work on the local file system.

Answer (score 0):

Says

> File operation not permitted. Access to path '' is denied.

When you try to reach Documents folder or another file localy. I'm using Silverlight 4 and I can play some http files on the net. But can't play an ftp file like ftp://user:pass@address/myVoicefile.snd, When I look at given error

> .Net's verify method return not supported path.

So using an inner html page in silverlight app. or if your sound files are limited copying these files in /ClientBin in your web app is an alternative.